# Best Type of RAID for VMware VMFS

Tags: raid, esxi, iscsi

What type of RAID volume would be the best type to use for a VMFS Volume on my ESXi Hosts. I will be using iSCSI shared storage between a cluster.  I have the options of 0,1,5,1+0.   I have narrowed down my decision to 1+0 or 5.

Answer (score 2):

It really will depend on the kind of VMs you will be running. Are the applications write heavy or read heavy?

Read heavy systems will be ok on a RAID-5, while RAID-10 (1+0) will be much faster on writes. The parity calculation with raid 5 takes a beating to RAID-5.

RAID-10 also has the disadvantage of using half of your storage for redundancy.

RAID-5 will really need a battery-backed cache for any decent performance.

I am using RAID-10 on an Openfiler SAN at work and it works nicely as the app is very write heavy.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of factors which you havent provided.

However 1+0 offers the great performance and high availability, at the cost of losing the more disk capacity than RAID 5.